# How can I make Notepad++ actually start maximized?

Tags: notepad++

When I start a new instance of Notepad++, its window is always slightly larger than the screen, not actually maximized. That really bothers me because I have two monitors, and the extra size spills over onto the second, an effect which looks really strange.

I looked through the settings dialogs and found nothing relevant. I found guides online that explain how to make a desktop shortcut create a maximized window, but I virtually always start Notepad++ via a context menu, so that tweak doesn't help.

I'm running the installed version of Notepad++ v6.3 on 64-bit Windows 8.1.

How can I make Notepad++ start with an actually maximized window?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### How can I make Notepad++ start with an actually maximized window?

You need to upgrade your version (v6.3) of Notepad++.

There was a bug (fixed in v6.4):

> Fix the bug of Window position not saved/restored properly

Source [Notepad++ v6.4 new features and bug fixes](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.4.html)

Notes:

- The latest version (as of 30 May 2016) is v6.9.2.
- The version I am running (v6.8.6) remembers the size, position and windows state (minimised/normal/maximised) it had when I closed it after a restart.

Comment: Ah, that did it. Interestingly, the in-program updater didn't work (some sort of checksum error), so I got the updater from the web site, and automatic syntax highlighting was temporarily broken, but now everything is good.

Comment: @BenN Perfect :p